# Manipulate works OK on desktop, but not in cloud

Tags: manipulate, wolfram-cloud

I have a problem with following Manipulate. In desktop Mathematica everything is okay but when I evaluate this code in cloud and publish the output cell, it flickers and both the values and chart aren't displayd correctly.

Is there something which causes this behaviour? If yes, how can I repair it?

Also, I know that my code sucks, but I couldn't come up with any better idea how to make (at least at desktop) the chart and calculations work. If there is better way how to do it, I'd be very thankful for any advice. However, the chart and switching between calcualtions of several unknowns must definitely be included.

[image: desktop]
[image: in cloud]

```
Manipulate[
 (* calculate result ---------------------- *)
 Switch[unknown,
  A,
    rules = {P -> mP, i -> mI, f -> mF, k -> mK*mF};
    output = N[result[equation, rules, unknown]];
    mA = output,
  P,
    rules = {A -> mA, i -> mI, f -> mF, k -> mK*mF};
    output = N[result[equation, rules, unknown]];
    mP = output,
  i,
    rules = {A -> mA, P -> mP, f -> mF, k -> mK*mF};
    output = N[result[equation, rules, unknown]];
    mI = output,
  k,
    rules = {A -> mA, P -> mP, i -> mI, f -> mF};
    output = N[result[equation, rules, unknown]];
    mK = output/mF
  ];
 
 isError = MemberQ[{output, rules}, "ERR", Infinity];
 
 If[isError,
  output = Style["Error", Red];
  effI = Style["Error", Red];
  plot = "";
  Pause[0.5]
  ,
  effI = DecimalForm[
    N[100*EffectiveInterest[mI/100, 1/mF]], {Infinity, precision}];
  
  (* chart ---------------------- *)
  chartRules = {P -> mP, i -> mI, f -> mF};
  maxPeriod = mK*mF;
  If[chartMax > maxPeriod, chartMax = maxPeriod];
  If[chartMin > chartMax, chartMin = chartMax];
  
  listI = 
   Part[Table[
     Part[equation /. chartRules, 2] - mP, {k, 0, maxPeriod}], 
    chartMin + 1 ;; chartMax + 1];
  listP = 
   Part[Table[mP, {k, 0, maxPeriod}], chartMin + 1 ;; chartMax + 1];
  listTotal = 
   Transpose[{N[listP, {Infinity, precision + 1}], 
     N[listI, {Infinity, precision + 1}]}];
  
  plot = BarChart[
    listTotal,
    ImageSize -> Medium,
    BarSpacing -> Large,
    ChartLayout -> "Stacked",
    ChartLabels -> {Range[chartMin, maxPeriod], None}]
  ];
 
 (* display output ---------------------- *)
 Grid[{
   {unknown, "=", DecimalForm[output, {Infinity, precision}]},
   {"Effective int. rate", "=", effI},
   {plot, SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft}},
  Alignment -> Left],
 
 (* display controls ---------------------- *)
 {{unknown, A, "Unknown"}, {A, P, i, k}},
 {{precision, 2, "Precision"}, 0, 10, 1, Slider, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 
 Delimiter,
 
 Style["Proměnné", Bold],
 
 PaneSelector[{
   A -> Grid[{
      {mPLabel, mPControl},
      {mILabel, mIControl},
      {mFLabel, mFControl},
      {mKLabel, mKControl}},
     Alignment -> gridAlignment],
   P -> Grid[{
      {mALabel, mAControl},
      {mILabel, mIControl},
      {mFLabel, mFControl},
      {mKLabel, mKControl}},
     Alignment -> gridAlignment],
   i -> Grid[{
      {mPLabel, mPControl},
      {mALabel, mAControl},
      {mFLabel, mFControl},
      {mKLabel, mKControl}},
     Alignment -> gridAlignment],
   k -> Grid[{
      {mPLabel, mPControl},
      {mALabel, mAControl},
      {mILabel, mIControl},
      {mFLabel, mFControl}},
     Alignment -> gridAlignment]},
  Dynamic@unknown],
 
 Delimiter,
 
 Style["Graf", Bold],
 
 {{chartMin, 0, "od"}, 0, Dynamic@maxPeriod, 1,
  TrackingFunction -> (chartMin = 
       If[# > chartMax, chartMax, If[# < 0, 0, #, 0]]; &),
  ControlType -> Slider,
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 
 {{chartMax, 1, "do"}, 0, Dynamic@maxPeriod, 1,
  TrackingFunction -> (chartMax = 
       If[# < chartMin, chartMin, If[# > mK*mF, mK*mF, #, 1]]; &),
  ControlType -> Slider,
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 
 (* initialization ---------------------- *)
 Initialization :> (
   equation = A == P*(1 + i/(100*f))^k;
   
   (* funkce -----------------------------*)
   range[value_, min_, max_] := 
    If[value === Null, 1, Clip[value, {min, max}]]; 
   result[equation_, rules_, variable_] := (
     res = If[MemberQ[rules, "ERR", Infinity] === True,
       {},
       If[Or[variable === k, variable === i],
        NSolve[{equation /. rules, variable >= 0}, 
         WorkingPrecision -> Infinity],
        NSolve[{equation /. rules}, WorkingPrecision -> Infinity]]];
     
     If[res === {},
      res = "ERR",
      res = variable /. res[[1]]]
     );
   
   (* controls ---------------------- *)
   mAControl = 
    InputField[Dynamic[mA, (mA = range[#, 1, Infinity]) &], Number];
   mPControl = 
    InputField[Dynamic[mP, (mP = range[#, 1, Infinity]) &], Number];
   mIControl = 
    InputField[Dynamic[mI, (mI = range[#, 1, Infinity]) &], Number];
   mKControl = 
    InputField[Dynamic[mK, (mK = range[#, 1, Infinity]) &], Number];
   mFControl = 
    PopupMenu[
     Dynamic@mF, {1 -> "year", 2 -> "half year", 4 -> "quarter year", 
      12 -> "month"}];
   
   mP = 1000;
   mA = 1100;
   mI = 10;
   mF = 1;
   mK = 1;
   
   (* labels  --------------------------- *)
   labelLength = 35;
   mALabel = StringPadRight["Future value", labelLength];
   mPLabel = StringPadRight["Present value", labelLength];
   mILabel = StringPadRight["Interest rate (percent)", labelLength];
   mFLabel = StringPadRight["Frequency", labelLength];
   mKLabel = 
    StringPadRight["Interest. periods", labelLength];
   gridAlignment = Left;
   ),
 AppearanceElements -> None
 ]
```

Comment: It seems that the root cause of the problem was the BarChart - I tried SynchronousUpdating->False but it didn't work. When I removed the chart everything worked fine. 

So I decided to use ListPlot (which doesn't look as nice but it's better then nothing) that seems to work in cloud.